# javafx8 candle stick chart can't getrid of the stale data

Tags: javafx-8

I used the sample candle stick chart code to draw  chart. When I worked in the java7 ,the chart worked  fine. But when I tried in the Java8. there is a problem.
I tracked the problem like this:this code is from the sample code of Ensemble ：CandlStickChart.java

```
 @Override protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
        // we have nothing to layout if no data is present
        if(getData() == null) return;

        // update candle positions
        for (int seriesIndex=0; seriesIndex < getData().size(); seriesIndex++) {
            Series<Number,Number> series = getData().get(seriesIndex);
            Iterator<Data<Number,Number>> iter = getDisplayedDataIterator(series);
            Path seriesPath = null;

            if (series.getNode() instanceof Path) {
                seriesPath = (Path)series.getNode();

                seriesPath.getElements().clear();

            }
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(i++); // the different place
                Data<Number,Number> item = iter.next();
                double x = getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(getCurrentDisplayedXValue(item));
                double y = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(getCurrentDisplayedYValue(item));
                Node itemNode = item.getNode();
                CandleStickExtraValues extra = (CandleStickExtraValues)item.getExtraValue();
                if (itemNode instanceof Candle && extra != null) {
                    Candle candle = (Candle) itemNode;
```

this is part of the code.the problem is with the "the different palce"
for the iter.hasNext() will preserve the stale value.so, every time I set in new data。the list is further long .
the setdata code like ：

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> newData
                = FXCollections.<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>observableArrayList();

  for (int j = 1; j <= leno; j++) {
            newData.add(。。。。。。。);//
series.getData().clear();
 series.setData(newData);
```

When I remove the stale data by Iter.remove the exception is:we don't support removeing items from the diplayed data list.

Comment: please someone chould show me how to  get rid of the stale data. PS:Now I just cut the Iter.hasnext() so it whould not load the stale data.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you are describing - could you please provide a sscce (small standalone runnable code example) that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two calls to [removeDataItemFromDisplay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html#removeDataItemFromDisplay-javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series-javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data-) to the *dataItemRemoved* method.

Note: I made *series* and *item* final in the example code.

```
@Override
    protected void dataItemRemoved(final Data<Number, Number> item,
            final Series<Number, Number> series) {
        final Node candle = item.getNode();
        if (shouldAnimate()) {
            // fade out old candle
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), candle);
            ft.setToValue(0);
            ft.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    getPlotChildren().remove(candle);
                    removeDataItemFromDisplay(series, item);                    
                }
            });
            ft.play();
        } else {
            getPlotChildren().remove(candle);
            removeDataItemFromDisplay(series, item);

        }
    }
```